# BrowserRouter with trailing / causes manifest error

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

if I use a path like this one without a trailing slash `/` I dont get any errors...

```
<Route path = '/confirm_email' component = {Confirm} />
```

if I add a trailing slash like this

```
<Route path = '/confirm_email/' component = {Confirm} />
```

or like

```
<Route path = '/confirm_email/:test' component = {Confirm} />
```

or even like

```
<Route path = '/confirm_email/:test/' component = {Confirm} />
```

The error I get in the browser console is `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.` and when I click the error it points at `<!DOCTYPE html>` If I add a console.log() to the page, the log shows first then the error.

I have found that If i remove the below code from the index.html page the error stops.

```
    <script>
      const darkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches || false;
      const favicon = document.getElementById('favicon');
      const manifest = document.getElementById('manifest');
      function switchIcon(darkMode) {
        if (darkMode) { 
          favicon.href = 'favicon-dark.ico';
          manifest.href='manifest-dark.json' 
        } else {
        favicon.href = 'favicon-light.ico';
        manifest.href='manifest-light.json' 
        }
      }
      window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener( "change", (e) => switchIcon(e.matches));
      switchIcon(darkMode);
  </script>
```

The contents of manifest-dark.json is

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }    
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I do initially load the light version, then switch to the dark version.

```
<link rel="manifest" id='manifest' href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest-light.json" />
```

Comment: where is the error, browser dev console, terminal, typescript? Also when does it happen upon click or prior to that if page renders

Comment: The error is in the terminal, and the page can console.log first then shows the error

Comment: so its a compile time error, do you know if its typescript compiler error or your build compile error?  are you able to post full stack trace

Comment: Sorry I wrote that wrong the error is in the browser's console as seen here: https://i.imgur.com/pTGPLV9.png I did notice the console.log fires 2 times

Comment: apparently it is complaining that your manifest has syntax error. Do you know the content of your manifest.json? Also can you check if you are not getting any network error like 404

Comment: I checked the network tab in dev tools and there are no 404 errors, the manifest i added above ^^

Comment: Try loading dark as default and observe if you get the same error as if dont seem like you have any syntax error in your json file so probably dynamic switching is causing it, in which case you can possibly defer hardcode loading, detect dark/light mode first and then load manifest by injecting in the DOM

Comment: Ok I've switched the initial load of the manifest to the dark and the error persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199129/discussion-between-bill-and-rikin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there was path issue as you had `href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest-light.json"` in your link tag but not in your JS code `manifest.href='manifest-dark.json'`

Since that URL is injected from your build process you would have to plug that variable in your JS code as well.